# Pyqt5 QComboBox drop down menu texts are overlapping

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

[image]

If you can see there is not any gap between 2 rows in drop-down menu. If I click on any of one the above and below rows are cutting. I wanted to put gap between 2 rows I have tried using `QComboBox AbstractItemView::item{#padding properties}`but it did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

I am attaching another image to clarify.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I solved it changing the font size.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for comment. I am new to Stack overflow so do not know

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the size of font and also height from text bar and it solves my problem. At first my font size was 14px and height of Text box was 30px so it is overlapping. I have put 3 rows inside Text box. Each one of them were using 33% so I need something that fits in the height or I can change the height so I did change the height and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the "setView" method:

```
my_combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
my_combobox .setView(QtWidgets.QListView())
```